# LibGDX How to slide spritebatch from bottom of screen using LibGDX?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I want to slide the spritebatch up from the bottom of the screen to the desired position. Right now, I just have the spritebatch drawing to the screen without any animation.

```
private void drawScoreboard() {
    batcher.draw(scoreboard, 12, midPointY - 40, 115, 65);
}
```

I'm fairly new in LibGDX so I am not sure how to create the sliding effect.

Comment: The SpriteBatch is a tool for drawing objects at a certain position in "world space" to "screen space", with the translation between the two being defined by a projection matrix. The SpriteBatch itself has no notion of a position or moving. An open ended question like this with many possible solutions depending on your needs is better suited to the Libgdx forum than this site, which is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scene2d(stage or actor) or Universal tween engine to achieve this.